# How to update angular service and directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services

I have a slider that should communicate with an external web service, sending and retrieving data.
For this I have a JSONP angular service and more directives dependent by this service.

What is the way to update the service(for sending and retrieving) and directives when user drags the slider?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What relevant code can you show (e.g. the service code, the markup for the slider, etc)?

Comment: do you want to send a request every time the user drags the slider handle, that means every time the slider value changes?

Comment: @DonJuwe. Thanks for asking. Yes, I need to send some data to the external webservice for receiving other data that I need to display it in the application. I made those things using ajax and JS classic but I want to refactor all the application using Angular, this is an opportunity to learn it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer to my comment I suggest using an [AngularJS compatible slider](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-slider) which works well with `ng-model`. On stop, you may access its value and send your request, e.g.:

HTML:

```
<div ui-slider="{orientation: 'vertical', range: 'min'}"  min="0" max="25" step="1" ng-model="myModel"></div>
```

Controller Code:

```
$scope.slider = {
    'options': {
        stop: function (event, ui) { 
           // do your request
        }
    }
}
```

Other slider links:

http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-switch/slider-css3-transition-animation
http://venturocket.github.io/angular-slider/

Comment: Your proposal is good, replacing the Jquery UI Slider with an angular one can offer me the possibility to manage the events, updating the service and then the directives. I think I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Please withdraw your upvote so I cant get a golden badge then :) Just accept the answer without upvoting thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't let me to undo it.

Comment: Can you please give me a hint how can I update my directives based on the service updates?(Should I move your controller sugestion in a link function. I need to update DOM contents based on the webservice result). Thanks.